# Re-writing tomcat 8 urls

Tags: regex, tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat-valve

I have two tomcat applications deployed under two different contexts:

```
someurl.com/context1/
someurl.com/context2/
```

I need to intercept urls in the form:

```
someurl.com/clientname/context1/
```

and redirect them to url:

```
someurl.com/context1/clientname
```

where "clientname" is dynamic

I have tried using a rewrite valve in the  element of my tomcats server.xml file, but it still works only for urls which include the context. i.e.:

```
someurl.com/context1/clientname/context1
```

gets re-written to

```
someurl.com/context1/clientname
```

using the following regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^.*/context1/.*$

RewriteRule ^.*/context1/(.*)$  /context1/$1    [L]
```

Is there a way to globally re-write urls in such a way that the context is not taken into account?

Comment: Is your goal to avoid having to do this in Java at the filter level? I'm guessing you rather have this as a configuration as oppose to a class/jar file correct?

Comment: Correct. I actually found the solution, so will post an answer a bit later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your question, your group regex (using $1) helped me to modify the last part of a URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of digging around I found out a really easy way of achieving the desired result. The trick is to set up a root context without any actual application being deployed there. Then to that root context a RewriteValve is added like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="ROOT" path="/" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
</Context>
```

It is important that the crossContext is set to true, so the root context can communicate with the lower level contexts.

Then in WEB-INF of the root context the following rewrite.config will do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^/.*/context1/(.*)$     /context1/$1    [L]
```

which basically means: capture all ur's which have the form: **clientname/context1/etc** and route them to **context1/clientname/etc**