# Tomcat URL Redirect Issue

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8, tomcat-valve

Tomcat : 8.5.30
Java 8
OS : macOS Mojave 10.14.6

As a sample project, I'm trying to redirect any url : /{dynamicValue}/entity/{entityID} to /entity/{dynamicValue}/entity/{entityID}. Here the 'entity' is my context and will be referencing entity.war inside the webapps directory.

Context File (Path : apache-tomcat-8.5.30/conf/context.xml):

```
<Context docBase="ROOT" path="/" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
</Context>
```

RewriteConfig File : (Path : apache-tomcat-8.5.30/webapps/ROOT/WEB_INF/rewrite.config.xml)

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$   $2/$1/$2/$3 [L,NE]
```

Exposed endpoint : /{dynamicValue}/entity/{entityID}

Internal Endpoint : /entity/{dynamicValue}/entity/{entityID}

Any call directly made to 'Internal Endpoint' works fine. But, API calls to 'Exposed Endpoint' are not being redirected to the 'Internal Endpoint'. (returning 404)

Any suggestions ?

Reference : [Re-writing tomcat 8 urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402975/re-writing-tomcat-8-urls)

Comment: Your rewrite.config file is incorrectly named.

Comment: Oh that was weird. Saving and opening it in sublime added a *.xml extension at the end. Renamed and saved using terminal worked fine. Redirect is working as expected. Pls post your comment as answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in rewrite.config file name.

Furthermore, Tomcat does not support dynamic/regex based contexts and that is because of well defined principles. If you have such a use case, I'd strongly advise figuring out the exact need for this and if you could improve the modelling.